# Youtube integration with IOS application.

Tags: ios, ios6, youtube-api, redirect

I am facing problem with integrating Youtube with my app in IOS. While making request to authorisation in order to get request token, i need to pass a redirect URL (similar to FB or Twitter integration).

Problem is that while registering my application to Youtube, i can see 2 redirect URI's present : "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" & "http: //localhost".

If i am using any of these i am getting token id in browser itself without getting redirected to my app.

If I am using any other redirect URI, created within application then server is giving me error.

Any suggestions how to do this correctly so that browser redirects to my app after successful authorisation.

Comment: It might be easier to use this toolkit, which handles all of this for you: https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are registering your project wrong.

In your [dev console](https://code.google.com/apis/console), you have to create a client id as "Installed application -> iOS"

All you will need is bundle id (package name) and/or app store id

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim, but I have declared the bundle ID, i think Youtube does not redirects to application like FB or twitter. See under devices tab in this link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#devices

Comment: It does indeed. Your application will pop up the authentication and when user authorized, it will get back to your app. Devices flow is for devices like TVs etc with limited input capabilities. Use gtmOAuth2 toolkit https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/ and implement - (IBAction)startOAuthFlow:(id)sender; We'll try to put an open-source example soon.

Comment: I have created client ID and secret and when invoked search api, auth error 1001 is logging. Is it mandatory to login and fetch auth key for you tube search api?